# decoding inter-octet binary data

Tags: python, binary

I've got a bytestring `"\x56\x20"`, which is two sets of data, a (12 bits) and b (4 bits).

The unpacked data is expected to be:

a = 86
b = 2

Where:

```
a = int("056", 16)
b = int("2", 16)
```

I know I can use `binascii` to convert the bytestring to a hex string and then work slice magic on it, but that seems messy.

I looked at `struct` but couldn't figure out a method to split out 12 bits/4 bits.

```
>>> import binascii
>>> two_octets = "\x56\x20"
>>> hex_str = binascii.hexlify(two_octets)
>>> temp_a, temp_b = hex_str[:2], hex_str[2:]
>>> a_part, b_part = reversed([c for c in temp_b])
>>> int(a_part + temp_a, 16)
86
>>> int(b_part, 16)
2
>>>
```

Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: If `\x56\x20` is to be split in a 12 and a 4 bit section, you get 1378 and 0, *not* 86 and 2.. Unless this is little-endian, and thus should be interpreted as `\x20\x56` really.

Comment: good point, I'm just looking at the raw bytes in a hex editor, so yes it appears it should be \x20\x56.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be interpreting the data as little-endian. To decode, decode with `struct`, then use bitshifting and a mask to interpret them:

```
import struct
two_octets = '\x56\x20'
values = struct.unpack('<H', two_octets)[0]
a = values & 0xFFF  # Select right-most 12 bits
b = values >> 12    # Select left-most 4 bits
```

Comment: @monkut: It's fine. :-) I'm surprised at the downvote, that's all. As documented in the [Python datamodel](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), python integers explicitly support bitmasking and shifting, because it's the accepted way of dealing with situations like these (also see http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitManipulation).

Comment: ok, say I have a definition for these fields, something like fields = (12, 4).  given that definition is there a programmatic way to get the  mask?

Comment: @monkut: Sure: `mask = (2 ** fields[0]) - 1`.

Answer (score 2):

For binary analysis of non whole-byte data an external module like [bitstring](http://python-bitstring.googlecode.com) might help (it certainly will when things get more complicated than this):

```
>>> from bitstring import BitArray
>>> a = BitArray(bytes='\x20\x56')
>>> a.unpack('uint:4, uint:12')
[2, 86]
```

Comment: thanks! Looks nice, but I want to stick to the standard lib for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import struct
>>> divmod(struct.unpack('<H', '\x56\x20')[0], 2 ** 12)
(2, 86)
```

Comment: If your about `divmod` function, it just return tuple `(a / b, a % b)`.

Comment: Really, `divmod`? Too-clever-by-half, this would be thrown out in a codereview.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, please, can you explain what you mean?

Comment: Using `divmod` to extract the two separate values from the two bytes, is perhaps a semi-clever, but is far removed from the normal way of dealing with such bytes. It makes your code un-maintainable, I would expect a semi-experienced developer to understand bitshifting and masking, but when encountering this trick would require a lot more head-scratching than is strictly necessary. Thus, if I came across this in a code-review, I would reject it or replace it with a bitshift-and-mask operation instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, to be honest, I do not know to what problems this may cause. Also, in my case, the shift is given one time, and in your - twice, which can lead to potential problems. If I had a more difficult case to work with shifts, and would also be used bitshifting. But in this I see no reason to not use the simple division.

Comment: @defuz: I shift *once*, and mask *once*. The problem lies in the code maintainability, divmod is not the standard way to deal with the problem. Using `2 ** 12` as the divisor alone is confusing, it's not clear that this is a 12-bit 'mask' you are using.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, can by replaced by `1 << 12`, but, I think you are right. Ok, I guess I was too naive. Sorry for *my* down vote. But unfortunately my "vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited".